# Using Apex Controller to Load a VisualForce Page to take Certain Values

Tags: apex, javascript, controller

I'm trying to retrieve the value from my javascript below that is inside the VisualForce Page.

```
 savingImage(imgData);
```

I need to transfer this value into my Apex controller to create the image to be store into the Document Folder.

I'm using the Developer Console to test out the Apex Class codes because I need a scheduler to get a screenshot of the page and store it into the Document folder.

I need a scheduler because the images are images of the salesforce chart and I'm using a scheduler to get a photo of the VisualForce Page and save it into the Document folder everyday at a certain time rather then I personally everyday go and get a screenshot of the page and upload the file.

---

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page name="Custom_Dash_Board"  showHeader="true" sidebar="false" title="Custom DashBoard" renderAs="PDF" controller="SaveImage">

<html>
<div id='screenshot'>
<h1>Company Performance Dashboard</h1>

<div id='screenshot'>
 <h1>Combine Dashboard </h1>
 <img src='https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rs=....' />
<img src='https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rs=....' />' />
</div>



<script>
 html2canvas($('#screenshot'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(',')[1];
        //SaveImage.saveImage('001i000000gDY4Z',imgData,handleResult); // 
        savingImage(imgData); // Calling action function which will call controller method
    }
});

function handleResult(result,event) {
 if(result.success) {
    alert('Screenshot attached');
  } else {
    alert('Error: '+result.errorMessage);
  }
}
</script>

<apex:form >
 <apex:actionFunction action="{!SavingImage}" name="savingImage" rerender="">

   <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!imageBody}" value="" />

</apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class Code**

```
public with sharing class SaveImage {

String imageBody{get;set;}

public void SavingImage(){
Document docatt = new Document();
docatt.Name = 'Salesforce.png';
    docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(imageBody);
    docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F001201p4Gi';
    docatt.IsPublic = true;
    docatt.ContentType = 'image/png';

    insert docatt;
 }
}
```

**Error Message From Developer Console**

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SaveImage].saveimage()
```

**Error Message when I try to Save if I do not change the Apex Class Name**

```
This schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress
```

**Full Debug Log**

```
39.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
17:11:23.0 (548966)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0056F00000746ij|jerome|Singapore Time|GMT+08:00
17:11:23.0 (582067)|EXECUTION_STARTED
17:11:23.0 (586612)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|VisualForce View State
17:11:23.0 (5854703)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VisualForce View State
17:11:23.0 (8003704)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

**Error Message From Developer Console**
[image]

Comment: Did you tried using actionfunction ?

Comment: actionfunction? I'm not familiar with it even after reading about [it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and I would suggest you to go through [ActionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) first before using it. Let me know if you have any query.

```
<script> 
      html2canvas($('#screenshot'), {
onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(',')[1];
   savingImage(imgData); // Calling action function which will call controller method
}
 });

 function handleResult(result,event) {
 if(result.success) {
  alert('Screenshot attached');
} else {
 alert('Error: '+result.errorMessage);
}
}
 </script>                   
// Use this action function inside <apex:form> of your visual force page(javascript function and actionfunction should be in same page)

 <apex:actionFunction action="{!savingImage}" name="savingImage" rerender="">

    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!imageBody}" value="" />

</apex:actionFunction>
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class SaveImage {
 String imageBody{get;set;}

public void savingImage(){
 Document docatt = new Document();
  docatt.Name = 'Salesforce.png';
        docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(imageBody);
        docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F001201p4Gi';
        docatt.IsPublic = true;
        docatt.ContentType = 'image/png';

        insert docatt;
 }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the latest error into the post

Comment: Try removing the commented line.  SaveImage.saveImage('001i000000gDY4Z',imgData,handleResult);

Comment: Please search for "SaveImage" method as you might have called this method that's why you are getting that error